# Android SQLite - "cannot access column 3" etc

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a new SQLite database in Android via this method:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE events (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, chosenSpot TEXT, chosenTime TEXT, chosenDate TEXT, chosenGroup TEXT);");

}
```

In short, it has 5 columns, one for the Id, the rest for a chosen{Spot/Time/Date/Group}

To get the spot given a Cursor c, i succeed with c.getString(1).

But this fails for c.getString(2..4) and i don't know how to further debug this, how to check my db size, etc. I checked the column count with c.getColumnCount() and it returns 2 when it should be 5!

What's up with that?

=edit=
my log cat:
[image]

Comment: you can use the sqlite command through adb. Just run `adb shell` then use sqlite with the following structure: `sqlite3 data/data/com.your.package/databases/yourDbName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using cursor.getColumnIndex("_id") to get column ID's.

`cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("_id") );`

Comment: How would i use this in my getter methods? i have getTime(Cursor c), getDate(c), getGroup(c), etc., each in columns 1 - 4...i followed a tutorial with 3 variables, and i extended it by one more...not sure what went wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to drop your old table and then create the new one.

```
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE events");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE events (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, chosenSpot TEXT, chosenTime TEXT, chosenDate TEXT, chosenGroup TEXT);");
```

**Comment out** drop command at next run time when you have new table already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether the Database is getting created properly. I suggest you get the db file out of your emulator and then view it with some sqlite data viewer. There is a very nice plugin in Firefox to do it.

Once you are sure that the database is fine we can move to the next bit of your cursor problem.